# adding Access-Control-Expose-Headers in AWS Lambda response header

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am making a REST call to a lambda service and getting the response with some expected data along with response header information. I am trying to access one of the header key-value in client side, but when i read the header information in javascript, i only get content-type. In browser developer's network tab i can see the header key-value set. I tried to add Access-Control-Expose-Headers in lambda's Cloudformation template for that particular key, but i get another exception while deploying it on AWS. Not sure what i am missing. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure, you have `options` method in your path in API Gateway:

```
Api:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
  Properties:
    Name: "my-api"
    Body:
      swagger: "2.0"
      info:
        version: "2018-03-20T13:41:34Z"
      basePath: "/"
      schemes:
      - "https"
      paths:
        /my-path:
          options:
            responses:
              "200":
                headers:
                  Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
                    type: "string"
                  Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
                    type: "string"
                  Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
                    type: "string"
            x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
              responses:
                default:
                  statusCode: "200"
                  responseParameters:
                    method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS'"
                    method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,x-api-key,x-amz-security-token,Auth'"
                    method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
              requestTemplates:
                application/json: "{\"statusCode\":200}"
              passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
              type: mock
          post:
          ...
```

From your Lambda you can set header as follows:

```
exports.handler = async event => {
    ...    
    return {
        isBase64Encoded: false,
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {                             
            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Content-Type,...',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }
}
```